# FireDAC Advantage DB Connection Type

Tags: database, delphi, firedac, advantage-database-server

I am contemplating the migration from Advantage Native Delphi components to FireDAC.  I have been searching for a way to determine how with FireDAC I can determine the method that was used to connect to the server - Remote, Local, AIS (Internet).

I would be looking for the equivalent of TAdsConnection.ConnectionType.

Thanks
Gary Conley

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you're looking for is called [**AdsGetConnectionType**](https://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage10.1/index.html?ace_adsgetconnectiontype.htm). Its import you can find declared in the **FireDAC.Phys.ADSCli** module, but it's not used anywhere.

But it's not so difficult to get its address and call it by yourself. For example (not a good one):

```
uses
  FireDAC.Stan.Consts, FireDAC.Phys.ADSCli, FireDAC.Phys.ADSWrapper;

var
  FTAdsGetConnectionType: TAdsGetConnectionType = nil;

type
  TADSLib = class(FireDAC.Phys.ADSWrapper.TADSLib)
  end;

function GetConnectionType(Connection: TFDConnection): Word;
const
  AdsGetConnectionTypeName = 'AdsGetConnectionType';
var
  CliLib: TADSLib;
  CliCon: TADSConnection;
  Status: UNSIGNED32;
  Output: UNSIGNED16;
begin
  Result := 0;
  CliCon := TADSConnection(Connection.CliObj);
  CliLib := TADSLib(CliCon.Lib);

  if not Assigned(FTAdsGetConnectionType) then
    FTAdsGetConnectionType := CliLib.GetProc(AdsGetConnectionTypeName);

  if Assigned(FTAdsGetConnectionType) then
  begin
    Status := FTAdsGetConnectionType(CliCon.Handle, @Output);
    if Status = AE_SUCCESS then
      Result := Word(Output)
    else
      FDException(CliLib.OwningObj, EADSNativeException.Create(Status, CliLib, nil),
        {$IFDEF FireDAC_Monitor}True{$ELSE}False{$ENDIF});
  end
  else
    FDException(CliLib.OwningObj, [S_FD_LPhys, CliLib.DriverID],
      er_FD_AccCantGetLibraryEntry, [AdsGetConnectionTypeName]);
end;
```

Possible usage:

```
case GetConnectionType(FDConnection1) of
  ADS_AIS_SERVER: ShowMessage('AIS server');
  ADS_LOCAL_SERVER: ShowMessage('Local server');
  ADS_REMOTE_SERVER: ShowMessage('Remove server');
end;
```